# How to configure multiple NICs (re0, em0) | re0=default, em0=network | same network

Tags: networking, routing

I want do configure my FreeBSD-System to use **re0** as **default gateway** for all incoming/outgoing (internet) traffic and **em0** for a **specific network**, so I can easily control packets with **pf**.

My router is a FritzBox (192.168.178.1) and both nics (re0 and em0) are connected to this. DHCP is currently enabled and they get ips in the same network.

## Current Config

#### ifconfig

```
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags     Netif Expire
default            192.168.178.1      UGS         re0
127.0.0.1          link#3             UH          lo0
192.168.178.0/24   link#1             U           re0
192.168.178.33     link#2             UHS         lo0
192.168.178.199    link#1             UHS         lo0
```

#### rc.conf

```
ifconfig_em0="DHCP"
ifconfig_re0="DHCP"
```

## Desired Config

#### ifconfig  (snippet)

```
default            192.168.178.1      UGS         re0
192.168.178.0/24   link#2             U           em0
```

#### re0

- Default route
- IP no matter

#### em0

- Routing to 192.168.178.0/24
- IP in network 192.168.178.0/24

## Already tried

#### rc.conf

```
defaultrouter="192.168.178.1"
ifconfig_em0="inet 192.168.178.33  netmask 255.255.255.0"
ifconfig_re0="inet 192.168.178.199 netmask 255.255.255.0"
static_routes="my"
route_my="-net 192.168.178.0/24 -iface em0"
```

## My Summary

It seems, re0 is always the first interface thats configured by OS and therefore the default gateway, including the route into my network 192.168.178.0/24.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? I **don't** want to use **re0** for routing into my network. This should **only** done by **em0**.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who has dealt with my question.

I found a solution. It turns out, that the order in "network_interfaces" seems to be important. My current config looks like

```
ifconfig_re0="NOAUTO"
ifconfig_em0="NOAUTO"

network_interfaces="em0 re0"
ifconfig_em0="inet 192.168.178.33 netmask 255.255.255.0"
ifconfig_re0="inet 192.168.178.199 netmask 255.255.255.0"
defaultrouter="192.168.178.1"
```

This does the trick. The desired configuration stays after rebooting.
Kind regards